# Magento 2 Products missing in category pages post Migration

Tags: magento2, admin, category, products, migration

I've recenty attempted to Migrate my products and categories from Magento 1 to Magento 2 via Ubertheme and run across a strange issue.

I have two categories, "Brands" and "Type", which have a number Sub-categories, these appear to be displaying correctly when hovered over (drop down menu):

The other two categories are "Discounted Products" and "Back in Stock", these should just be links which go straight to the category pages where all the products are displayed in grids.

On "Discounted products" there are some products displayed but there are also blank pages, in particular, when I go to a Blank page the options for Pagination (navigate to a different page, display number of products etc), are missing, also if I choose "all" from the products dropdown it goes to a blank page.

"Back in stock shows no items in the category main page whatsoever despite the fact that if I create a new category and add the exact same products it shows them on the category home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've looked into this and it seems that the issue here was a number of 0KB (possibly corrupted) images in the file system.

I had to SSH into the pub folder and ran the command:

```
find . -size 0
```

This provided me with a list of the files that were measured at 0KB. several of these were images, as Images are usually some of the larger files in a system this indicates a problem.

Removing these image files seems to have resolved the issue that I was having.